Exact completion moment of the Spring Boot Redis executePipelined method
I use the executePipelined  method to push some records to Redis. And then some other code.
stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(new RedisCallback<Object>() {
    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
        StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
        for(int i=0; i< batchSize; i++) {
            stringRedisConn.hMSet(hashKey, data);
        }
        return null;
    }
});

System.out.println("All records pushed");

I want know the exact completion moment of the executePipelined method. Is it,

After dispatching all the Redis commands to the Redis server or

After successfully finish executing all the commands in the Redis
server.


